# How can I display the same DOM across several tabs in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to build a chrome extension that allows the user to have an independent subwindow that is the same in each tab (for example you are taking notes and the notes are synchronized among each tab). Also, clicking a link should not destroy this subwindow.

One solution is to inject an iframe in each tab, and try to synchronize this data serverside and send back to each client tab, as it is updated.

This seems very tedious, plus the iframe would be provided by a third party, and I want to make it the easiest for them.

Is there a way I can have a shared dom piece and display it in its current state across several tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an API (still experimental as of Chrome 17) that does more or less exactly what you want. If you visit `about:flags`, and enable "Panels" (they're enabled by default in Dev and on Canary (and on ChromeOS)), you'll be able to use [`chrome.windows.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create) with a type of `panel` to create a floating pane that exists independently from the browser window. That would likely meet your need.

Take a look at the [Google Talk](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd) extension for an example of how it might work.

Comment: Awesome! this seems to be exactly what I need. You say it's experimental, yet Google talk has 143,430 users. Are all those users on the dev channel with "panels" enabled? Do you know if this experimental feature will be released in the next mainstream chrome versions?

Comment: The Google Talk extension falls back to opening popup windows when the `panel` functionality doesn't exist: see the chrome.windows.create documentation for details. I don't have a solid release date for you with regard to panels, but it's certainly getting closer. The team put out a call for feedback in October: http://osdir.com/ml/chromium-extensions/2011-10/msg00056.html